# How can I get the easing function from CSS to JavaScript as the cubic-bezier function with numbers

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I can get a custom easing function as a function (as numbers), but I don't know how to convert named easing functions such as `ease-in` into numbers. Is this possible?

The reason why to do this is to synchornize timing in Javascript to an animation.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  const i = document.querySelector("i")
  const b = document.querySelector("b")

  const iFunction = getComputedStyle(i)["animation-timing-function"]
  const bFunction = getComputedStyle(b)["animation-timing-function"]

  // I want both in the format `cubic-bezier(a, b, c, d)` - how?
  console.log("Noooo: ", iFunction)
  console.log("Yesss: ", bFunction)

  // This is what I want to work for both
  const span = document.querySelector("span")
  const curveAsNumbers = bFunction.match(/[\d]+[.\d]*/g)
  const easing = BezierEasing(...curveAsNumbers)
  const anim = b.getAnimations()[0]
  const duration = anim.effect.getTiming().duration
  setInterval(() => {
    const easingFunctionX = (anim.currentTime % duration) / duration
    const percent = easing(easingFunctionX)
    span.innerText = (percent*100).toFixed(0)
  }, 10)
 
})
```

```css
i,b { display: inline-block; }
i {
  animation: rota 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
b {
  animation: rota 2s infinite cubic-bezier(1, 0.11, 0.8, 0.3);
}

@keyframes rota {
    0% {rotate: 0deg;}
  100% {rotate: 360deg;}
}
```

```html
<div><b>❤️</b> Animation at <span>xxx</span>%</div>
<div><i></i> Animation at ???%</div>

<p>Note how both take 2s to run, but the timing functions differ</p>

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bezier-easing@2.1.0/dist/bezier-easing.min.js
"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually map the keyword back to their cubic counterpart.
Based on the documentation from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function#ease-in-out)
a map like this could work

```js
{
  'ease':        'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1.0)',
  'ease-in':     'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0)',
  'ease-in-out': 'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.0, 0.58, 1.0)',
  'ease-out':    'cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0,  0.58, 1.0)'
}
```

*note that timing functions can also use `step(<number>, <direction>)` syntax, which this does not cover*

```js
const timingFunctionDictionary = {
  'ease': 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1.0)',
  'ease-in': 'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)',
  'ease-in-out': 'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.0, 0.58, 1.0)',
  'ease-out': 'cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.58, 1.0)'
}

const animationTimingFunctionToCubic = (timingFunc) => {
  // use dictionary to return the cubic equivalent, returns original input when mapping fails
  return timingFunctionDictionary[timingFunc] || timingFunc
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const i = document.querySelector("i")
  const b = document.querySelector("b")

  const iFunction = animationTimingFunctionToCubic(getComputedStyle(i)["animation-timing-function"])
  const bFunction = animationTimingFunctionToCubic(getComputedStyle(b)["animation-timing-function"])

  // both are now in the format `cubic-bezier(a, b, c, d)` - by using the dictionary to map them.
  console.log("from dic: ", iFunction)
  console.log("Yessssss: ", bFunction)

  // This will now work for both
  const spanB = document.querySelector(".p1")
  const spanI = document.querySelector(".p2")

  const curveAsNumbersB = bFunction.match(/[\d]+[.\d]*/g)
  const curveAsNumbersI = iFunction.match(/[\d]+[.\d]*/g)
  const easingB = BezierEasing(...curveAsNumbersB)
  const easingI = BezierEasing(...curveAsNumbersI)
  const animB = b.getAnimations()[0]
  const animI = i.getAnimations()[0]
  const durationB = animB.effect.getTiming().duration
  const durationI = animI.effect.getTiming().duration
  setInterval(() => {
    const easingFunctionB = (animB.currentTime / durationB) % 1
    const easingFunctionI = (animI.currentTime / durationI) % 1
    const percentB = easingB(easingFunctionB)
    const percentI = easingI(easingFunctionI)
    spanB.innerText = (percentB * 100).toFixed(0)
    spanI.innerText = (percentI * 100).toFixed(0)
  }, 10)

})
```

```css
i,
b {
  display: inline-block;
}

i {
  animation: rota 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}

b {
  animation: rota 10s infinite cubic-bezier(1, 0.11, 0.8, 0.3);
}

@keyframes rota {
  0% {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<div><b>❤️</b> Animation at <span class="p1">xxx</span>%</div>
<div><i></i> Animation at <span class="p2">???</span>%</div>

<p>Note how both take 20s to run, but the timing functions differ</p>

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bezier-easing@2.1.0/dist/bezier-easing.min.js
"></script>
```

*note that the percentage calculation was off, i've applied a small change there.*

Comment: Oh wow, I just now checked and the values are actually part of the spec :O https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-easing/#cubic-bezier-easing-functions 

Awesome, thanks!